# Is there a way to iterate a vector in reverse using for each loop?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to use for each loop because it doesn't go to NULL indices(I think) whereas in range for loop it goes through each and every index

Comment: q.v. [`rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin)

Comment: what are "NULL indices" ? You can use a loop with (reverse) iterators, there are no "NULL indices"

Comment: What are "null indices"? There shouldn't be any major difference between ranged-for and `std::for_each`.

Comment: A for-each loop goes to all the same indices as a loop over the indices in reverse (`for (ssize_t i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)`), so your premise is flawed. Iterating a `std::vector<type*>` will get the values that are `NULL` just as it gets the non-`NULL` values.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/o19sacME4

Comment: thank you for clarifying i thought that if there are 3 indices... lets say 0 1 and 2 ... if 0 and 1 are occupied by a value and 2 is empty then the iterator would skip index 2... but I was wrong :)

Comment: what do you mean with "2 is empty" ? Vectors have capacity and size. Capacity can be larger than size, but size is the number of elements, and they aren't "NULL"